# Converting strings to other datatypes in Red

Tags: type-conversion, red

What is the recommended way to convert a string to an integer in Red?

One way I found is:

```
load "123"
== 123
```

Is `load` the best way of getting an integer from a string in Red?

Is there any danger in using `load` in this way specifically if the string is from an unvalidated source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, that is the only way, as `to` action has not been implemented yet. It is safe using `load`, as it does not do any kind of evaluation and the construction syntax support is very basic (covering just none and logic values).

EDIT: `to` action is now available from v0.6.2 on, so `to-integer "123"` can be used too.

Comment: As of Red version 0.4.3 the to action works for this conversion:
`to integer! "123"`
`== 123`